# Find the id of a dict within a list, by matching the dict's value (without a loop)

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I have list as this :

```
[{"id": 101, "name": "music1"}, {"id": 102, "name": "music2"}]
```

how do I get a id of object matching with specific name:

for e.g,

```
input: music2
output : 102
```

Comment: ... Have you tried anything? Iterating over the list, checking the `'name'`, and getting the corresponding `'id'`? What exactly do you not know how to do?

Comment: If you are going to need to query this data a lot, why not just convert the entire thing to a dict or dicts?

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga was trying to find out if its possible without iterating a loop.

Comment: No, it isn't, it will require linear search of your list. To preform better, use a different data-structure.

Answer (score 0):

```
a = [{"id": 101, "name": "music1"}, {"id": 102, "name": "music2"}]

input = "music2"
for i in a:
    if i["name"] == input:
        print(i["id"])
```

Comment: thanks for the answer. i was trying if its possible without a loop.